# Is there a limit or penalty in resurrect an ally?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can revive a partner in the middle of a fight, just need a small cast on him.

But there is a limit of times I can resurrect the same person or penalty about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no penalty involved. I think the reason for the cast time is simply that you can not do this easily during busy fights. Other than that, though, you should be fine.